# Unable to fetch Web reference in CSOM while calling Method from Asp.net Core

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, asp.net

I am looking for DLL or NuGet Package which is Compatible with Asp.net core 2.1
I create one solution using Asp.net core 2.1 I also added one existing project which is in the .Net framework where the SharePoint code exists. When I added it to the solution and compiled it and it's perfectly built. I added reference in my Asp.Net core MVC Project And after building a solution, it's perfectly fine. I also added **app for Sharepoin**t Nuget Package and generated a token helper class in my asp.net project. 
Till now everything is fine. But when I called a method of Sharepoint Which I created in an Asp.net solution It giving me 400 bad requests error and ExecuteQuery is giving me an error. But when I called it from .Net console application it's perfectly executing.
Can you all please suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no solution available, but you can listen to Microsoft's roadmap on this in the [Microsoft 365 PnP – General M365 Developer SIG community call – 28th of May 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtusCyOYePs&feature=youtu.be&t=908) call. As you can see, they are targeted .NET Core 3.1 and not the 2.x branch.